# d3 quantile scale quantiles rounding

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making legends for a quantile scale:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(clr.quantiles())

legend.append("text")
    .text(String);
```

However this gives me a lot of decimals. Is there a way to round the quantile values? I tried using .nice() but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to round your quantile values try this

```
clr.quantiles().map(x => Math.round(x));
```

it'll return the same array with all the values rounded :)